# sklearn's KNN algorithm prediction running at drastically different speeds for different distance metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, distance, knn

I came to notice that sklearn's KNN algorithm equiped with Euclidean distance predicts several orders of magnitude faster than, say, with Manhattan distance. While it takes less than a minute on my hardware to compute predictions for my dataset (dimension 6250x500) with Euclidean distance, it takes over 20 minutes with the Manhattan metric. Why is that?

In my mind, there shouldn't be any computational difference between computing the L1 and L2 norms.